# Member of In queryBuilder

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, query-builder

I need to request some users by groups list. For this I must use "Member of" function same described here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

But in my projet, i prefer use doctrine queryBuilder (documented here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html) but i doesn't found any equivalent in query builder for the "Member of" DQL syntax.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MEMBER OF, and INSTANCE OF, just got recently added to the Expr* classes, as you can see in this commit:

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/400f420925eea9d50eee9ea3d78a847b381865ce

As far as I know, none of the stable releases include it at the moment, you have to wait for the next release.